# 0 DTU at Azure's SQL database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Why I have DTU=0 of SQL database on Azure during 5 minutes?
Is this Azure's bug?

[image: DTU=0 from 14:28 to 14:33]

Comment: We have zero information about your running app, aside from your activity graph. Could be lack of traffic. Could be your app instance recycling (maybe you're running in a Web app tier which got recycled?). Could be any number of things. As posted, not something that can be answered. And I don't see how you made the leap to it being "Azure's bug."

Comment: As David says, need more details like what app you are running, what is activity pattern of app, were there any other indicators that app is running too hot/too cold in same time window etc. Also, which region is this DB in?

Comment: How can I get list of sql queries?

Answer (score 2):

From your graph, my failing eyes tell me there are some plotted points and they don't make a perfectly horizontal line. That means there was some DTU usage in at least part of that 5 minutes period. Perhaps 1-2% or even 2.42%. Regardless, unless you can show you have active workloads running against this instance and there was no administrative operation/command taking place that blocks active workloads, there's really nothing to investigate here.